unable to raising exception part of unit test case for a function call, with in the targeted test function
I am trying to validate a test case exception raises condition but failing with "AssertionError: Exception not raised"
Main Module with a function to test
sample_module

from xyz import AbcClass

abc_class = AbcClass()

def func1():
    #few_steps
    abc_class.do_something()
    #few more steps

Test class
class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    doo something …
    sys.modules[‘xzy’] = MagicMock()

    def test_func1():
        do something …
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            with patch ("xyz.AbcClass") as mock:
                instance = mock.return_value
                instance.do_something.side_effect = Exception
                from src import sample_module
                sample_module.func1()

Failure Log
 with self.assertRaises(Exception):
E               AssertionError: Exception not raised
    
test_sample_module.py:125: AssertionError


Are you sure that your MagicMock() inputs will cause an exception or func1 has no async operation? Moreover, make sure that no exception is already handled in func1().

Peyman.H - 1. If you notice, I am trying to raise exception using “side_effect”, so it should not be dependent on inputs, is my understanding.
2. func1 is not and has no async call
3. Is not part of try - except block
Moreover these conditions are relevant if I call function with parameters and expecting it to fail as part of flow.
But I am trying to raise an exception using unittest framework.

Found the solution
with patch ("xyz.AbcClass") as mock:
mock.do_something.side_effect = Exception
with self.assertRaises(Exception) as ex:
from src import sample_module
sample_module.func1()
